# Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format textbox c#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have two textboxes in my form `txtbox1` is for salary and `txtbox2` is for result `(txtbox1 / 30)`.

I chosed custom format for `txtbox1` this is the code :

```
private void mtb_SJ02_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',') // 8 is back space
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // 13 is Enter
        {
            mtb_SJ02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(mtb_SJ02.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

The code work good as I want show me the number like this : 22.403,33
now i need to divide salary `(txtbox1.text/30)`.

I create a string variable called sj :

```
  string  sj;
```

Now i want to calculate the result and show it in the txtbox2  with the same Format `{0:#,##0.00}`. This is the code:

```
void calculate ()
{
    sj = ( Double.Parse(mtb_SALAIR02.Text ) / 30).ToString("{0:#,##0.00}");
    mtb_SJ02.Text = sj;
}
```

when i run the code i get this message error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqsPq.png)

so nay good idea how to do that plz ?

Comment: and whats in mtb_SALAIR02.Text when you get that error?

Comment: at run time it is empty

Comment: well then - theres you're issue, its empty - you need to work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for you all i think i fixed that by a friend

the solution is :

```
        string  sj;

    void calculator ()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtb_SALAIR02.Text)) return;
        mtb_SALAIR02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(mtb_SALAIR02.Text));
        sj = (Double.Parse(mtb_SALAIR02.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) / 30).ToString();
        mtb_SJ02.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(sj));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(textBox1.Text=="")
{
  textBox1.Text="0";
}
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
String sj = (Double.Parse(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) / 30).ToString();
textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(sj));
```

Comment: didn't work bro it show the same error at first Line : Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format can u help using TeamViewer ?

Comment: is textbox1 empty?

Comment: in run time yes it is empty but there is buttom get the salary from SQL DB .
when the textbox1 get the data from DB the calculator start working and show the result in textbox2 .

Comment: if it is empty put a condition and assign "0" to textbox

Comment: can u help with TeamViewer bro ?.. maybe i didn't understand u exactly

Comment: No teamviewer sorry, I made a change in code, please try